# HTML <span> questionn not sure

Tags: html, css

I have a div on which I placed a span and two other divs. one of the divs should appear just after span. so i gave position: absolute for the container div. the next div was supposed to place at top:80%. but since span takes up some with, the actual top ends up at 80%+span height. could u tell me a way to position it correctly, avoiding the spans height?

**html**

```
<div class="section" id="about">
  <div id="heading">
    <span>ABOUT</span>
  </div>
  <div id="about_definition">
    <p>about definition goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="about_services">
    <p>about services goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#about_definition {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 20%;
   background-color: white;
}
#about_services {
   position:relative;
   width: 100%;
   height:20%;
   top: 80%;
   background-color: red;
}
.section {
   height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XzrqB/)

Comment: Please, post code samples of HTML and CSS to help explain.

Comment: Patience, user, I'm looking at it now.

Comment: Seriously, you can't wait 5 minutes?

Comment: What do you mean "position correctly?"

Comment: i want the second div to be positioned at the bottom. but with this code, it's at the bottom+height of span.

Comment: I dont really get what you want to do. You should write it more clearly.

Comment: You need this: http://jsfiddle.net/XzrqB/1/ ?

Comment: Note : "relative" is misleading : It does NOT mean "relative to parent" but "relative to where it should normally appear". I think you need "absolute" here.

Comment: when i gave absolute, it went outside the container div which is static by default. with absoulte, it's with respect to the body. is it beacuse im in quirks mode?

Comment: you should (must) avoid quirks mode. Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your html page (before the `<html>` tag). With the jsfiddle I gave you, it is automtatically added. Tell me if this links is what you need : jsfiddle.net/XzrqB/1 : I placed the div so that it sticks to the bottom of the page.

Comment: with quirks mode, height=100% and such things wouldnt work unles specified in html, body selector. so it's not my cup of tea, i think

Comment: Yes, but you can put `html,body {height:100%}` in your CSS to solve this problem. Trust me, quirks mode is a real UB zone (UB = Undefined Behavior).

Comment: okay, mate. is body{height:100%} enough?

Comment: No. You would end up with a `<body>` which is 100% of `<html>` height, which is 0. Concerning CSS position, I strongly encourage you to follow this 10 steps guide : http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: And if you want to check the place that your elements take, it is quite easy with the chrome console (F12 when you are on chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning .section and #about_definition absolutely:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/XzrqB/3

```
#about_definition {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: white;
}
#about_services {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:20%;
    top: 80%;
    background-color: red;
}
.section {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: i have a couple of sections, mate. so i cant use absolute.

Comment: In that case, I think you're working too hard to force things into position. Web content should flow, especially in this age of mobile/responsive. I'd stick your footer to the bottom and let everything else stack naturally.

Comment: means giving bottom:0 and positioning absolutely respective to the static positioning of container?

Comment: Container must not be be positioned static.

Comment: i meant the original flow of the document.